# Remove values from lists of values in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am using Python 2.7 with Windows 7.

I have a dictionary and would like to remove values that correspond to (key, value) pairs from another dictionary.

For example, I have a dictionary `t_dict`. I would like to remove corresponding (key,value) pairs that are in the dictionary `values_to_remove` so that I end up with dictionary `final_dict`

```
t_dict = {
    'a': ['zoo', 'foo', 'bar'],
    'c': ['zoo', 'foo', 'yum'],
    'b': ['tee', 'dol', 'bar']
}

values_to_remove = {
    'a': ['zoo'],
    'b': ['dol', 'bar']
}

# remove values here

print final_dict
{
    'a': ['foo', 'bar'],
    'c': ['zoo', 'foo', 'yum'],
    'b': ['tee']
}
```

I have looked at similar pages on SO and the python dictionaries doc but cannot find anything to solve this specific problem:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict

[How to remove dictionaries with duplicate values from a nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11932175/how-to-remove-dictionaries-with-duplicate-values-from-a-nested-dictionary)

[How to remove a key from a python dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277432/how-to-remove-a-key-from-a-dictionary?rq=1)

**EDIT**

There cannot be duplicate values in `t_dict` per key. For example there will never be

`t_dict['a'] = ['zoo','zoo','foo','bar']`

Comment: You're not removing values from a dictionary. You're removing values from a **list**.

Comment: `for key, list_ in values_to_remove.items(): for word in list_: t_dict[key].remove(word)` <-- one way

Comment: can there be duplicates like t_dict['a']=['foo','foo'] and values_to_remove['a']=['foo'] ?

Comment: @sasha, good question, no there cannot be. I will edit my OP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since duplicates aren't possible, it might make sense to store the values as a `set`, not a `list`. If you can use a `set` for `t_dict`, the removal process is both faster and simpler to write (even faster if `values_to_remove` uses `set` or `frozenset` too):

```
for k, toremove in values_to_remove.viewitems():
    t_dict.get(k, set()).difference_update(toremove)
```

Use the above if `values_to_remove` expected to be small, or if `t_dict` is smaller, you could switch to the following to avoid the temporary `set()`s (the empty `tuple` is a singleton, so it costs nothing to use it with `dict.get`):

```
for k, v in t_dict.viewitems():
    v.difference_update(values_to_remove.get(k, ()))
```

Final option is the overly clever approach that removes the need for using `.get` at all by only processing keys that appear in both `dict`s (using `-=` requires both `dict`s to use `set` for values to be shorter/faster, you could go back to `difference_update` if you want to allow non-`set`s for `values_to_remove`'s values):

```
for k in (t_dict.viewkeys() & values_to_remove.viewkeys()):
    t_dict[k] -= values_to_remove[k]
```

Comment: Use `OrderedSet` if the order is important?

Comment: @sparkandshine: `OrderedSet` isn't part of the Python standard library (it only has `collections.OrderedDict` which can be used to emulate most `set` behaviors _except_ the set-specific operation I'm using here), but yeah, `OrderedSet` is an option if you're okay with the additional dependency.

Answer (score 5):

Try this,

```
for k, v in t_dict.items():
    for item in values_to_remove.get(k, ()):
        v.remove(item) 

# Output
{'a': ['foo', 'bar'], 'c': ['zoo', 'foo', 'yum'], 'b': ['tee']}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you loop inside the `if` to remove all of the values associated with `k` in `values_to_remove`? Or to simplify the code by combining check and iteration, `for k, v in t_dict.items():`, `for toremove in values_to_remove.get(k, ()):`, `v.remove(toremove)` (which also avoids needlessly looking up `t_dict[k]` as second time; you already got it from the `items` iteration).

Answer (score 2):

```
for key,values in values_to_remove.items():
    for value in values:
        if key in t_dict and value in t_dict[key]:
            t_dict[key].pop(t_dict[key].index(value))
```

Comment: Does not meet the requirements. You don't throw out the whole list, you pop the matching elements.

Comment: There weren't lists in the original question. Thanks for the downvote though

Comment: That would be a great excuse if StackOverflow didn't keep an edit history where I could easily see that the only thing that's been edited is the question title.

Comment: I meant first *question* asked in the OP, not the first *version* of the OP.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist: Not necessarily. Edits made before answers/comments are posted or before votes occur usually don't show up in the history. So you could load a question, compose answer, and while composing, question is edited "silently". No idea if that's the case here, but it could be.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Not that the most recent edit of the comment before yours doesn't make it pretty clear this answerer just didn't read the whole OP, but I've been here since 55 seconds after this was asked. There have always been lists.

Answer (score 1):

When you don't want to have the duplicated elements in your dict, and the order also not so important, why don't use `set` as you dic value?

```
t_dict = {
    'a': set(['zoo', 'foo', 'bar']),
    'c': set(['zoo', 'foo', 'yum']),
    'b': set(['tee', 'dol', 'bar'])
}

values_to_remove = {
    'a': set(['zoo']),
    'b': set(['dol', 'bar'])
}

for k,v in values_to_remove.iteritems():
    t_dict[k] = t_dict[k]-v

print t_dict

>>>{'a': set(['foo', 'bar']), 'c': set(['foo', 'yum', 'zoo']), 'b': set(['tee'])}
```

If the Order important for you, you can also use the OrderedSet like @sparkandshine in comment suggested. http://orderedset.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```
from ordered_set import OrderedSet
t_dict = {
    'a': OrderedSet(['zoo', 'foo', 'bar']),
    'c': OrderedSet(['zoo', 'foo', 'yum']),
    'b': OrderedSet(['tee', 'dol', 'bar'])
}

values_to_remove = {
    'a': OrderedSet(['zoo']),
    'b': OrderedSet(['dol', 'bar'])
}

for k,v in values_to_remove.iteritems():
    t_dict[k] = t_dict[k]-v

print t_dict

>>>{'a': OrderedSet(['foo', 'bar']), 'c': OrderedSet(['zoo', 'foo', 'yum']), 'b': OrderedSet(['tee'])}
```